# Net utility intuition

Tags: utility

Let us assume that a utility funciton is $U=C-L,$ or utility is consumption
less leisure. Suppose $C=10,$and $L=2.$ We get $U=8.$ My question
is: which 2 utility units are being subtracted from $C?$ The last
2 units? Any 2 units?

Comment: This might be useful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_utility

Comment: Thank you @MichaelGreinecker. Assume that utility is ordinal. If it is, is there a natural ordering in utility units? For instance, is there a unique first, second, and so on unit for a given utility level?

Comment: No, the point is that for ordinal utility, utility units are not defined.